# Multi-module via npm link and typescript local development

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsc

I'm trying to use NPM to link a dependent module B with its dependency A.  Using [this](http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears) as a guide, I've done the following.

Project A is defined as:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-link-failure-a",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/A.js",
  "typescript": "dist/A.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "npm link"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "merge2": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

A.ts

```
export class A {
    "foo":string;
}
```

`npm run-script setup` was executed to create a link from this directory to the global node_modules.

In project B:

```
{
  "name": "typescript-link-failure-b",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/B.js",
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npm link ../A"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "merge2": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

B.ts

```
import {A} from "typescript-link-failure-a"

class B {
    "foo":A;
}
```

I use NPM link to link back to project A.  I think the linking is working, as in Project B's node_modules, i can see project A.

however, when I try to

`import {A} from "typescript-link-failure-a"`, Intellij, VS Code, and TSC all fail saying they don't understand the module named typescript-link-failure-a.

Can anyone provide insight?

[github link to code example](https://github.com/benjaminabbitt/typescriptExplorations)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, project B needed to refer perform the NPM link to the *name* of project A, not the path.

Changing it to `npm link typescript-link-failure-a' as a command in the root of project B solved the problem.

Comment: Still doesn't work in IntelliJ. I can see the project in node_modules but when I go to its definition the IDE points to @types instead of @myBigProject/Dependency

Comment: it seems it doesn't work when I have a dependency declared in an organization, like @myOrg/myDependency but if I use only the simple name like myDependency, it works. :/